# Unindent does not match any outer indentation levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Attempting to run the following python code, I'm getting the Indentation error :

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    def fetch_words():
       with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t/txt') as story:
           story_words = []
           for line in story:
               line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
               for word in line_words:
               story_words.append(word)
    return story_words

def print_words(story_words):
   for word in story_words:
       print(word)

def main():
   words = fetch_words()
   print_words(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: The dupe handles all things: tabs vs spaces, wrong indentation, etc. The exact error message tells you more about your errors as well - and your posted code here would give you `IndentationError: unexpected indent`  and not the error you get in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this indentation works for you

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_words():
   with urlopen('http://sixty-north.com/c/t/txt') as story:
       story_words = []
       for line in story:
           line_words = line.decode('utf-8').split()
           for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
   return story_words

def print_words(story_words):
   for word in story_words:
       print(word)

def main():
   words = fetch_words()
   print_words(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: I'm now getting this :

Comment: File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request

Comment: python2 or python3? I tried the code with python3

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the `return story_words`, as you are trying to return out of a function.

EDIT

Also set the `story_words`, declaration on top of the `with open`.

Comment: Sorry, whoever edited/fixed incorrectly indented return story_words. I have it now under 'with'